# MinGW error about TITLEBARINFO not declared

Tags: c++, windows, gcc, window, mingw

I'm using the latest MinGW:

```
MINGWBASEDIR=C:\mingw
gcc version 4.7.0 (GCC)
gcc version 4.7.0 (GCC)
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.5
GNU ld (GNU Binutils) 2.22
GNU windres (GNU Binutils) 2.22
GNU dlltool (GNU Binutils) 2.22
GNU Make 3.82.90
#define __MINGW32_VERSION 3.20
#define __W32API_VERSION 3.17
```

This is the source file (test.cpp):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main(int Argc,char** Args) {
  printf("%d",sizeof(TITLEBARINFO));
}
```

This is how I compile it:

```
g++ -c test.cpp
```

And this is the error message reported by MinGW:

```
C:\temp>g++ -c test.cpp
test.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
test.cpp:5:22: error: 'TITLEBARINFO' was not declared in this scope
```

TITLEBARINFO is supposed to be declared in winuser.h which windows.h includes. 
I've checked these 2 header files in mingw/include dir, the definition of TITLEBARINFO is truly there. But I still get this compiler error, how strange!

Comment: try to `#define WINVER 0x505` (XP) before `#include<windows.h>`. many implementations defaults to 0x400 (WinNt) and you are using something that exist from Win2000

Comment: it seems to be working only with #define _WIN32_WINDOWS 0x410 //or above

Comment: The documentation says Windows2000 (should be 0x500). 0x410 is WinNtSp2. may be the functionnality had been introduces at that time, but officially documented only later. Good to know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gcc -c -D_WIN32_WINDOWS=0x0410  test.cpp`

MinGW apparently defaults to 0x0400.